# Optimization in Shaders

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I got following message while profiling in the xcode. It suggest that i am using 32 bit floating point. In any case there is no issue for me to use 16 bit precision floating point. but If i do that it shows error. [image]

how can i improve the performance following is the shader function. For texture sampling can we use half4.

```
struct VertexOutCalculatedTextureBezier {
    float4 pos[[position]];
    float4 color;
    float2 textureCoordinates;
    int8_t index;
};
struct BezierCalParameters
    {
        float2 a;
        float angle;
        float size;
        int8_t index;
    };
```

Vertex shader function which is suggested while profiling

```
vertex VertexOutCalculatedTextureBezier bezier_calculated_vertex_texture(constant BezierCalParameters *allParams[[buffer(0)]],
                                                                         uint vertexId [[vertex_id]],
                                                                         uint instanceId [[instance_id]])
{
    BezierCalParameters params = allParams[instanceId];
    VertexOutCalculatedTextureBezier vo;
    vo.pos.xy = params.a;
    if(vertexId % 4 == 0){
        vo.pos.x = params.a.x +   params.size * sinpi(params.angle) ; 
        vo.pos.y = params.a.y -    params.size * cospi(params.angle);
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,0);
        vo.index = params.index ;
    }else if(vertexId % 4 == 1){
        vo.pos.x = params.a.x +     params.size * cospi(params.angle);
        vo.pos.y = params.a.y +   params.size * sinpi(params.angle);
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,1);;
        vo.index = params.index ;
    }
    else if(vertexId % 4 == 2){
        vo.pos.x = params.a.x -    params.size * cospi(params.angle) ; 
        vo.pos.y = params.a.y -     params.size * sinpi(params.angle);
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(1,0);
        vo.index = params.index ;
    }
    else if(vertexId % 4 == 3){
        vo.pos.x = params.a.x -   params.size *  sinpi(params.angle);
        vo.pos.y = params.a.y +   params.size * cospi(params.angle) ;
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(1,1);
        vo.index = params.index ;
    }

    vo.pos.zw = float2(0, 1);
    return vo;
}
```

The fragment function corresponding to this function

```
fragment half4 bezier_fragment_calculated_texture(VertexOutCalculatedTextureBezier params[[stage_in]],
                                                  texture2d<float, access::sample>texture [[texture(0)]],
                                                   texture2d<float, access::sample> texture2 [[texture(1)]],
                                                   texture2d<float, access::sample> texture3 [[texture(2)]])
{

     constexpr sampler defaultSampler;

      if(params.index == 0) {
          float4 color =texture.sample(defaultSampler,  params.textureCoordinates) * float4(1,0,0,0.68);
          return half4(color);
      }else if(params.index == 1) {
            float4 color =texture2.sample(defaultSampler,  params.textureCoordinates) * float4(1,0,0,0.68);
            return half4(color);
       }else if(params.index == 2) {
            float4 color =texture3.sample(defaultSampler,  params.textureCoordinates) * float4(1,0,0,0.68);
             return half4(color);
      }

        float4 color =texture.sample(defaultSampler,  params.textureCoordinates) * float4(1,0,0,0.68);
        return half4(color);
}
```

Comment: Show your attempt to use half-precision floating-point and the error that you got.

Comment: In your fragment function, convert this to a switch on index so that your code cannot possible one of the if branches and also fall through. Optimizing the vertex function is not such a huge deal because it it executing far less than the fragment function which is run for each pixel.